# Why can I not reverse the result of str::split?

Tags: string, rust, string-parsing

According to the docs for [`Split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html), there is a `rev` method on the result of doing `split` on a string:

```
fn main() {
    let mut length = 0;
    let mut mult = 1;
    for part in "1:30".split(":").rev() {
        length += mult * part.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        mult *= 60;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>: std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:35
  |
4 |     for part in "1:30".split(":").rev() {
  |                                   ^^^ the trait `std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not implemented for `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` for `std::str::Split<'_, &str>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>: std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:17
  |
4 |     for part in "1:30".split(":").rev() {
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>` is not implemented for `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` for `std::str::Split<'_, &str>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::iter::Rev<std::str::Split<'_, &str>>`
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `rev()` is defined on the `Split` iterator only if it implements `DoubleEndedIterator`, but `Split` only implements `DoubleEndedIterator` if the searcher of the pattern you are splitting on satisfies `DoubleEndedSearcher`:

```
impl<'a, P> DoubleEndedIterator for Split<'a, P>
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: DoubleEndedSearcher<'a>,
```

The documentation lists which types implement [`DoubleEndedSearcher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.DoubleEndedSearcher.html). None of the types there correspond to `&str` pattern, so you can't use `rev()` when you split on string.

In your particular case, I guess, it is sufficient to change `split(":")` to `split(':')` (i.e. split on character instead of string) because the character pattern searcher *does* implement `DoubleEndedSearcher`.

Such features of Rust (conditional trait implementation and trait bounds local to a method) allow writing really expressive code, but they can be sometimes hard to read through.

Comment: It's not `str` that has to implement `DoubleEndedSearcher`, it's `StrSearcher` in this case.  I think.  That, or I read the impl of `Pattern` on `str` wrong...

Answer (score 14):

The other answers are correct, but I want to point out [`rsplit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.rsplit). This is probably more obvious and more performant.

So, why can't you use `rev`? As other answers state, it's not implemented for `StrSearcher`. But *why* is it not implemented? From the [`DoubleEndedSearcher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.DoubleEndedSearcher.html) docs:

> For this, the impl of `Searcher` and `ReverseSearcher` need
>   to follow these conditions:
>
> - All results of `next()` need to be identical
>     to the results of `next_back()` in reverse order.
> - `next()` and `next_back()` need to behave as
>     the two ends of a range of values, that is they
>     can not "walk past each other".

The problem with reversing the iterator using strings is this:

```
"baaab".split("aa") // -> ["b", "aa", "ab"];
```

However, if you were to start at the end of the string, you'd get something like:

```
"baaab".split("aa").rev() // -> ["b", "aa", "ba"]
```

Which is clearly not the same set of items in a different order!

Simply put, you *can't* reverse an iterator that is split on strings because there's no **efficient** way of knowing when the next result is. You'd have to split the entire string into a collection, then reverse the collection!

This is why `rsplit` exists - it means start at the end of the string and split to the beginning, in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: `StrSearcher` (the type that does searching for string patterns) doesn't implement `DoubleEndedSearcher` and, as such, the `split` iterator doesn't implement `DoubleEndedIterator` and, as such, you can't call `rev` on it.

If you look at the documentation on that page for `rev`, you'll see `where Self: DoubleEndedIterator`.  This means that `rev` is defined *if and only if* the type the `Iterator` trait is being implemented for (which is `Split`) *also* has an implementation of the `DoubleEndedIterator` trait.

If you look further down, you'll see:

```
impl<'a, P> DoubleEndedIterator for Split<'a, P>
where P: Pattern<'a>, P::Searcher: DoubleEndedSearcher<'a>
```

Thus, `DoubleEndedIterator` is implemented for `Split` *if and only if* both of those conditions are satisfied: `P` must be a `Pattern` and the `Searcher` type it defines must implement `DoubleEndedSearcher`.

Now, you're using a string literal as the pattern, so if you check the [documentation for the `str` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), you'll see:

```
impl<'a, 'b> Pattern<'a> for &'b str
```

Within that, the associated `Searcher` type is defined as:

```
type Searcher = StrSearcher<'a, 'b>
```

Nearly there!  Follow the link to the [documentation for `StrSearcher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/struct.StrSearcher.html) and...

...there's no implementation of `DoubleEndedSearcher`.  Thus, the required bounds are *not* satisfied and `rev` can't be used on the `Split` iterator.